# How can I solve "average" best rank-$1$ approximation?

Tags: matrices, optimization, least-squares, quadratic-programming, rank-1-matrices

Assume I want to minimise this

$$ \min_{x,y} \left\| A - x y^T \right\|_{\text{F}}^2$$

then I am finding best rank-$1$ approximation of $A$ in the squared-error sense and this can be done via the SVD, selecting $x$ and $y$ as left and right singular vectors corresponding to the largest singular value of $A$.

Now instead, is possible to solve the following for $b$ also fixed?

$$ \min_{x} \left\| A - x b^T \right\|_{\text{F}}^2$$

If this is possible, is there also a way to solve

$$ \min_{x} \left\| A - x b^T \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 + \left\| C - x d^T \right\|_{\text{F}}^2$$

where I think of $x$ as the best "average" solution between the two parts of the cost function?

I am of course longing for a closed-form solution but a nice iterative optimisation approach to a solution could also be useful.

Comment: what does the subscript $F$ in $||\cdot ||_F$ signify?

Comment: The Frobenius norm

Comment: @ThomasArildsen, You should mark question as answered or say what's missing in the answers.

Answer (score 3):

$$\| \mathrm A - \mathrm x \mathrm b^{\top} \|_{\text{F}}^2 = \cdots = \| \mathrm b \|_2^2 \, \| \mathrm x \|_2^2 - \langle \mathrm A \mathrm b , \mathrm x \rangle - \langle \mathrm x , \mathrm A \mathrm b \rangle + \| \mathrm A  \|_{\text{F}}^2$$

Taking the gradient of this cost function,

$$\nabla_{\mathrm x} \| \mathrm A - \mathrm x \mathrm b^{\top} \|_{\text{F}}^2 = 2 \, \| \mathrm b \|_2^2 \, \mathrm x - 2 \mathrm A \mathrm b$$

which vanishes at the minimizer

$$\mathrm x_{\min} := \color{blue}{\frac{1}{\| \mathrm b \|_2^2} \mathrm A \mathrm b}$$

Note that

$$\mathrm A - \mathrm x_{\min} \mathrm b^{\top} = \mathrm A - \mathrm A \left( \frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b } \right) = \mathrm A \left( \mathrm I_n - \frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b } \right)$$

where

- $\frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b }$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the line spanned by $\mathrm b$, which we denote by $\mathcal L$.
- $\left( \mathrm I_n - \frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b } \right)$ is the projection matrix that projects onto the orthogonal complement of line $\mathcal L$.

Hence, the minimum is

$$\| \mathrm A - \mathrm x_{\min} \mathrm b^{\top} \|_{\text{F}}^2 = \left\| \mathrm A \left( \mathrm I_n - \frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b } \right) \right\|_{\text{F}}^2 = \color{blue}{\left\| \left( \mathrm I_n - \frac{ \,\,\,\mathrm b \mathrm b^{\top} }{ \mathrm b^\top \mathrm b } \right) \mathrm A^\top \right\|_{\text{F}}^2}$$

which is the sum of the *squared* $2$-norms of the projections of the rows of $\rm A$ (i.e., the columns of $\rm A^\top$) onto the orthogonal complement of line $\mathcal L$.

---

[matrices](/questions/tagged/matrices) [rank-1-matrices](/questions/tagged/rank-1-matrices)

Comment: Great Answer! +1.

Comment: For the case:

$$ \left\| A - x {b}^{T} \right\|_{2}^{2} + \left\| C - x {d}^{T} \right\|_{2}^{2} $$

The solution is given by $ {x}_{min} = \frac{ Ab + Cd }{ \left\| b \right\|_{2}^{2} + \left\| d \right\|_{2}^{2} } $.

Comment: Though I think you should insert it into your answer. If it is a credit thing, feel fre to make it your own edit.

Comment: I validated it before posting.

Comment: @Royi The different LaTeX style bothers me. It clashes. In any case, I verified your work and it is indeed correct.

Answer (score 1):

This is a Convex Optimization Problem and you can easily solve it using CVX:

```
numRows = 5;

mA = randn([numRows, numRows]);
vB = randn([numRows, 1]);


cvx_begin('quiet')
    cvx_precision('best');
    variable vX(numRows)
    minimize( norm(mA - vB * vX.', 'fro') )
cvx_end

disp([' ']);
disp(['CVX Solution Summary']);
disp(['The CVX Solver Status - ', cvx_status]);
disp(['The Optimal Value Is Given By - ', num2str(cvx_optval)]);
disp(['The Optimal Argument Is Given By - [ ', num2str(vX.'), ' ]']);
disp([' ']);
```

If you formulate your expression using the Trace Operator you'll also be able to solve it easily in other simple methods.

Comment: Why use CVX to solve an *unconstrained* least-squares problem?

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo, I was short on time and I wrote this can be easily solved in other methods as you did :-). My point was to show this is a Convex Problem hence easily solveable as the **Frobenius** norm is a norm.

Answer (score 1):

You already have solutions with CVX (convex optimization), but in fact you can solve this using simple ordinary linear least squares and representing matrix multiplication with Kronecker products. Let $M_E$ represent multiplication by $E$ (from the right) and $v_A,v_C,v_x$ be the respective vectorization of $A,C,x$ we can rewrite it:

$$\min_{v_x}\left\{\|v_A- M_{b^t}v_x\|_2^2 + \|v_C- M_{d^t}v_x\|_2^2\right\}$$

Which you can expand using $\|Y\|^2 = Y^TY$, then expand, differentiate, sum up and set derivative equal $0$ and solve.

You can read more about the details of the vectorization on [Wikipedia entry Kronecker Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_product)

Answer (score 0):

$
\def\LR#1{\left(#1\right)}
\def\op#1{\operatorname{#1}}
\def\trace#1{\op{Tr}\LR{#1}}
\def\frob#1{\left\| #1 \right\|_F}
\def\qiq{\quad\implies\quad}  \def\mt{\mapsto}
\def\p{\partial}  \def\grad#1#2{\frac{\p #1}{\p #2}}
\def\c#1{\color{red}{#1}}
\def\fracLR#1#2{\LR{\frac{#1}{#2}}}
\def\Sj{\displaystyle\sum_{j=1}^n}
\def\Sk{\displaystyle\sum_{k=1}^n}
\def\P{{\large\Psi}}
$Generalizing your second question a bit further, consider the following function
$$\eqalign{
\P &= \Sk\frob{A_k-xb_k^T}^2
 \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \qquad \quad
}$$
which can be rewritten using [Einstein Summation](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/EinsteinSummation.html)
and [Double-Dot Products](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Product_of_dyadic_and_dyadic)
$$\eqalign{
\P &= \LR{A_k-xb_k^T}:\LR{A_k-xb_k^T} \\
 &= \LR{xb_k^T:xb_k^T} \;-\; 2\LR{A_k:xb_k^T} \;+\; \LR{A_k:A_k} \\
 &= (b_k^T b_k)\LR{x:x} \;-\; 2\LR{A_k b_k}:x \;+\; \LR{A_k:A_k} \\
}$$
Calculate the gradient (NB: dummy index $k$ replaced by $j$ in the first term)
$$\eqalign{
d\P &= (b_j^Tb_j)\LR{2x:dx} \;-\; 2\LR{A_k b_k}:dx \;+\; 0
 \qquad \quad \\
 &= 2\LR{b_j^Tb_j x - A_k b_k}:dx \\
\grad{\P}{x} &= 2\LR{b_j^Tb_j\,x-A_k b_k} \\
}$$
and solve the $\sf zero\ gradient$ condition for $x$
$$\eqalign{
b_j^T b_j\,x = A_k b_k \qiq
\c{x = \fracLR{A_k b_k}{b_j^T b_j}\equiv\fracLR{\Sk A_k b_k}{\Sj b_j^T b_j}}
\\
}$$

---

For reference, here are the rules for manipulating double-dot products
$$\eqalign{
F:G &= \sum_{i=1}^m\sum_{j=1}^n F_{ij}G_{ij} \;=\; \trace{F^TG} \\
G:G &= \frob{G}^2 \qquad \{ {\rm Frobenius\;norm} \}\\
F:G &= G:F \;=\; G^T:F^T \\
\LR{XY}:G &= X:\LR{GY^T} \;=\; Y:\LR{X^TG} \\
}$$
where $\LR{F,G,X,Y}$ are arbitrary matrices with dimensions
$${
\def\R#1{{\mathbb R}^{#1}}
F,G \in\R{m\times n} \qquad
X \in\R{m\times p} \qquad
Y \in\R{p\times n} \\
}$$